# Text Not Changing While Using Tkinter In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i am making a project for school about welsh history and legends but can't get the two buttons (English & Cymraeg) To Change Two Labels When I Click Them. Any Help Will Be Appreciated!!

```
from tkinter import BOTH, Canvas
from tkinter import *

Titlet = 'Welsh History And Legends'
startt = 'Click Here To Start'

master = tk.Tk()
master.title('2020 Coding Challenge - Josh Allan')
master.configure(background = 'black')


def English():
    Titlet = 'Welsh History And Legends'
    startt = 'Click Here To Start'

def Welsh():
    Titlet = 'Hanes A Chwedlau Cymraeg'
    startt = 'Cliciwch Yma I Cychwyn'   

title = tk.Label(master, text = (Titlet), font = 'fixedsys 20 bold', fg = 'white', background = 'black')
title.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2)
ph = tk.Label(master, bg = 'black')
ph.grid(row=2)
LangE = tk.Button(master, text = 'English', font = 'Verdana 9 bold', fg = 'gray', background = 'black', command = English())
LangE.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
LangC = tk.Button(master, text = 'Cymraeg', font = 'Verdana 9 bold', fg = 'gray', background = 'black', command = Welsh())
LangC.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
ph = tk.Label(master, bg = 'black')
ph.grid(row=4)
press_start = tk.Button(master, text = (startt), font = 'Verdana 9 bold', fg = 'gray', background = 'black')
press_start.grid(row = 5, columnspan = 2)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Be careful, `import *` is generally bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not require the () at the end of your command = function

For example:
instead of

```
LangE = tk.Button(master, text = 'English', font = 'Verdana 9 bold', fg = 'gray', background = 'black', command = English())
```

put

```
LangE = tk.Button(master, text = 'English', font = 'Verdana 9 bold', fg = 'gray', background = 'black', command = English)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i've already tried this, the buttons still do nothing unfortunately

Comment: Have you packed your buttons?

Comment: It Wouldn't let Me But I realise the buttons aren't the problem, its the fact it's not changing the labels

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variables and have your functions `English` and `Welsh` to configure your label. However, I would prefer using `tk.StringVar` and `textvariable` option for your label.

```
import tkinter as tk


master = tk.Tk()
Titlet = tk.StringVar(master, 'Welsh History And Legends')
master.title('2020 Coding Challenge - Josh Allan')
master.configure(background = 'black')


def English():
    Titlet.set('Welsh History And Legends')

def Welsh():
    Titlet.set('Hanes A Chwedlau Cymraeg')  

title = tk.Label(master, text = (Titlet), 
                 font = 'fixedsys 20 bold', 
                 fg = 'white', 
                 background = 'black',
                 textvariable=Titlet)
title.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2)
ph = tk.Label(master, bg = 'black')
ph.grid(row=2)
LangE = tk.Button(master, text = 'English', font = 'Verdana 9 bold', 
                  fg = 'gray', background = 'black', command = English)
LangE.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
LangC = tk.Button(master, text = 'Cymraeg', font = 'Verdana 9 bold', 
                  fg = 'gray', background = 'black', command = Welsh)
LangC.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
ph = tk.Label(master, bg = 'black')
ph.grid(row=4)

tk.mainloop()
```